# MySQL Query Performance with a Derived Query

Tags: mysql, performance

I am looking at a few queries for performance and made a change to a query, which is based on the following examples. The change turned a 6 minute query into one which completes in few seconds and I was wondering why? How has this altered things to such an extent?

In the example, please assume the BOOK table to contain the general details for all books in a library and the FORMATS table contains details, such as HARDBACK, PAPERBACK and eBOOK (allowing for new formats to be added) where there is a key (called FORMATID) linking the two tables.

*Query executes in 6 minutes*

```
select b.bookid, f.formatname
from book b
inner join formats f on f.formatid = b.formatid

select b.bookid, f.formatname
from book b
left join formats f on f.formatid = b.formatid
```

*Query executes in 12 seconds*

```
select b.bookid, (select f.formatname from formats f where f.formatid = b.formatid)
from book b
where b.formatid is not null

select b.bookid, (select f.formatname from formats f where f.formatid = b.formatid)
from book b
```

In the above, the first query of each pair achieves INNER JOIN results and the second, achieves LEFT JOIN. The results difference on my database is 295166 and 295376 rows; the ties differences remain pretty much the same.

[added] For confirmation; I have tested this (with the same results) by creating the two test tables mentioned herein, populating the BOOKS table with ~1 million rows and NOT applying any index or other optimisation.

Comment: What about indexes? Did you change those ?

Comment: Nothing else was changed at all. In fact, I had the two queries open in two separate windows and was running each query in turn. The execution times were consistent (as per the post).

Comment: could you give us a CREATE TABLES and some sample data? I'd like to test it on localhost. And if possible a `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` before your SELECT statement could give us some more insight.

Comment: Sorry, I will check, but I don't think that I can provide the exact details from our database (due to our company disclosure policy) and all I could provide would be a mimic of the data, which would be the same as I have described in the post. Also, I have replicated the same results on a few different tables. I am thinking that the reason for this  must be down to the way in which SQL compiles the query for execution, rather than the actual structure/index of the tables.

Comment: your join, did you try specifying the kind of join? So, add legt

Comment: I was going to shrug a little at that; but I guess you make a valid point for investigation. In their default states the join on the first query would be an INNER JOIN and by using the derived query, I am making it a LEFT JOIN. I have edited the queries, one with the INNER specified and the other with a where clause for "formatid is not null"

Comment: does it make a big difference? As in, when you do the left join ?

Comment: There was no significant difference in time, between the LEFT/INNER joins.

Comment: I meant between the left join and the 6 minute query and the 12 second query

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I edited the original post to have all four of the queries; both of the two queries listed under "6 minutes" take about 6 minutes to run; and both listed under 12 seconds, take about 12 seconds. In both instances; the derived query is considerably faster.

Comment: _First_ we need to see what indexes you have.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  _Then_ we need to see `EXPLAIN SELECT` to see what the Optimizer did.  Only _then_ can we possibly answer your question about why one formulation is faster than the other.  Otherwise, it is guesswork.

Comment: @RickJames appreciate that, and I would have assumed/asked the same myself. But I have tested the same scenario on freshly created tables (no indexes or other optimisation) and populated with a high volume of records and got the same results. Try it for yourself with the two simple tables; populate the BOOK table with a significant number of rows.

Comment: If InnoDB, is `formatid` the `PRIMARY KEY` of `formats`?  If not, why not?

Comment: @RickJames yes, the "id" is the PK.

Comment: `id` and `formatid` are different; which is it?

Comment: I do apologise; my previous comment stated "id"; instead of "formatid"